# About queries in many to many relation

Tags: laravel

How I make query to get or fetch all records of parent table in many to many relation. for example the records of Table user and job. The ids of user and job stored in pivot table Job_User.In La-ravel 5.2

Comment: `Parent::with('child')->get()`? Am I missing something?

Comment: will it work for many to many relation

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: My questions is how i can only fetch the records of user and job whose id save in pivot table